# is there a directional companion to layoutMarginsGuide?

Tags: ios, layout, autolayout, ios-autolayout, margins

layoutMarginsGuide seems to pick up layoutMargins instead of directionalLayoutMargins

Is there a way to switch tethering to respect directionalLayoutMargins
instead of layoutMargins or do I need to set layoutMargins in superview based
on directionalLayoutMargins and text direction???

Answer (score 0):

apparently layoutMarginsGuide does respect directionalLayoutMargins
though they are clamped to some minimum values
(viewRespectsSystemMinimumLayoutMargins to false is of no use it turned out)